# Go, не могу до конца понять указатели

Tags: golang, указатели

есть вот такой небольшой кусок кода.

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Power int
}

func (p *Person) Super() {
    p.Power += 1000
}

func main()  {
    p := Person{"Mike", 1000}
    p.Super()
    fmt.Println(p.Power)
}
```

Но иногда я вижу что при объявлении структуры додают амперсанд, `&Person{"Mike", 1000}` какова цель этого? потому что вывод один и тот же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указатель это ссылка на объект. Если мы обращаемся к объекту по ссылке и меняем данные, то данные меняются у оригинального объекта. Если мы обращаемся по значению, то, как бы, копируем объект, если изменим его данные, то оригинальный объект останется прежним.

Например, мы создаем Майка. Очевидно, что человека не нужно копировать, поэтому лучше сохранить ссылку. Допустим, Майк входит в структуры Семья и Работа:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func (p *Person) GrowUp() {
    p.Age += 1
}

type Family struct {
    Husband *Person
    Wife    *Person
}

type Work struct {
    Director  *Person
    Employees []*Person
}

func main()  {
    p := &Person{Name: "Mike", Age: 30}
    f := Family{Husband: p}
    w := Work{Director: p}
}
```

Т.е. если вывести возраст у мужа в семье f и у директора в фирме w - будет 30 лет. Потом Майк повзрослел `p.GrowUp()`. И если снова проверить возраст у мужа и директора, то получим 31.

```
func main()  {
    p := &Person{Name: "Mike", Age: 30}
    f := Family{Husband: p}
    w := Work{Director: p}
    p.GrowUp()
    fmt.Println(f.Husband.Age, w.Director.Age)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Vn_uLZd6zuR

Если убрать указатели, то после изменения возраста Майка, возраст директора и возраст мужа не изменятся - https://play.golang.org/p/lJNW2I9rcC5

Answer (score 1):

если Вы пишите вот так

```
p := Person{"Mike", 1000}
```

то p  - это просто переменная типа структура Person

Если же так

```
p := &Person{"Mike", 1000}
```

то p - это указатель на структуру типа Person

И если в втором случае можно распечатать значение вот так

```
fmt.Println(*p)
```

То, в первом так делать нельзя.

Но почему вывод один и тот же? просто go скрывает в многих случаях разницу между указателем и просто переменной.

Comment: Как я понял, `*` он просто указывает что в эту область памяти можно что - то положить, и еще вопрос, вы написали,  ```p - это указатель на структуру типа Person``` но все же, зачем он здесь? делает какие то дополнительные возможности?

Спасибо!

Comment: звездочка - это либо указание на то, что тип - указатель, либо разыменовывание указателя. Что именно она делает - нужно смотреть по контексту. Зачем здесь указатель? я не знаю, но иногда он бывает очень сильно нужен. К примеру, если объект очень большой, и  у нас массив таких объектов, то копирование всего этого может занять много времени.

Answer (score 1):

Метод Super в качестве получателя требует тип *Person, но в коде аргументом является тип Person.
В таких случаях компилятор неявно получает адрес аргумента-получателя и передаёт его вызываемому методу. Если же вызывать Super сразу с аргументом-получателем *Person, то неявного получения адреса не требуется.
Сделано это, чтобы упростить код и не писать следующее:

```
(&p).Super()
```

И наоборот, если бы Super требовал тип Person в качестве получателя, а вызывался с аргументом *Person, то компилятор неявно выполнил бы разыменование указателя и Super получил бы копию экземпляра Person.